# problem in opencart admin panel, when click any menu it redirect to login page again

Tags: session, opencart-3

i use open cart 3.x
after i login to admin panel,
if i click on any menu link, it tell me :  Invalid token session. Please login again

how do i fix that ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is fixed automatically and the issue happen because the hosting and domain was new
after 2 days, it is fixed automatically
thanks for all